# Trying to get two argument in discord command (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to get two arguments in my command. This is what I am trying to do:

```
@client.command()
async def hii(ctx, limit=1, tries=2):
    await ctx.send(f"{limit}, {tries} was given")
```

Here, I might not need both values. When I try running this command in discord using:

```
/hii 4 5
```

4 is saved at limit and 5 is saved at tries. I might only need tries and work with default limit. How can I create placeholders for limit and tries and work on it.

This doesn't work:

```
/hii tries=5 limit=4
```

Comment: Maybe consider typing.Optional, it might fit your needs

Comment: The docs explain how to add optional arguments: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/commands.html#typing-optional

Answer (score 1):

A quick note: `typing.Optional` **doesn't work** because both options are of the same type. Try it yourself, `args(ctx, limit: typing.Optional[int] = 1, tries: int = 2)`.

---

The way to go here is to use `Greedy` to consume as many ints as possible. Note that we can silently ignore any additional numbers as this is default behavior in discord.py anyways.

```py
@client.command()
async def args(ctx, ints: commands.Greedy[int]):
    limit = 1
    tries = 2
    ints = ints[:2]  # silently ignore any other ints passed

    if len(ints) == 2:  # both were passed properly
        limit, tries = ints
    elif len(ints) == 1:  # only 1 was passed
        tries = ints[0]
    await ctx.send(f'ok, given {limit=}, {tries=}')
```

Here's what it outputs:

[image]

---

Here's also a way to accept keyword arguments using a custom converter and regex:

```py
class KeywordArgumentConverter(commands.Converter):
    async def convert(self, ctx, token):
        m = re.match('(\\w+)(=)(.+)', token)
        if m is None:
            raise commands.BadArgument('invalid format, need key=value')
        return (m.groups()[0], m.groups()[2])

@client.command()
async def keyword_magic(ctx, kwargs: commands.Greedy[KeywordArgumentConverter()]):
    await ctx.send(f'ok, got these kwargs: `{kwargs}`')
```

[image]

Comment: Sidenote: instead of a keyword args converter and some regexes, dpy 2.0 now has support for Flags out of the box:  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html?highlight=flag#flagconverter

Comment: typing.Optional definetely works. although this is extremely well done it is unnecessary. He is using slash commands.

Answer (score -2):

You can use typing.Optional and give them a default.

```
@client.command()
async def hii(ctx, limit: typing.Optional[int] = 1, tries: typing.Optional[int] = 2)
     await ctx.send(f"{limit}, {tries} was given")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]